# How to install Debug version of .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, debugging

I am successfully able to debug into .NET framework source code on my machine. But I can't see the values of most of the variables/objects while debugging .NET framework source code. An example is shown below:

[image]

I know the reason is because the when you install .net framework on your machine, the assembles in GAC are all built in release mode (optimized).

And so I need to know how to install Debug build of .NET framework on my machine? Are there any instructions given somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft only publishes public symbols for some assemblies. To debug local variables and so on you need private symbols which are exclusively to Microsoft support team.

There is no debug version of .NET Framework and you don't even need that in most cases. What exactly do you want to debug that requires such information?

Comment: Sometimes exceptions are thrown in .net framework code (especially serialization exceptions). I am unable to find the root cause of it without copy pasting the exception on google :-). I want to debug code end to end. The other day I was doing unit testing, and test just aborts showing a serialization exception in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll. I generated PDB and Source for it but still wasn't able to debug properly as during step through, it was jumping around randomly.